# Display CLOB in Jasper

Tags: java, jasper-reports, clob

My query in Jasper got CLOB data, but I'm not able to display it in my report, I even tried some of the solution that I found in this forum.

Both of these were not working:

```
new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader($F{clob_data}.getAsciiStream())).readLine()


$F{clob_data}.getSubString( 1l, ( new Long( $F{clob_data}.length() ) ).intValue() )
```

even debug with no error, after run it in web application, it will show:

```
error=net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRExpressionEvalException: Error evaluating expression : 
    Source text : ...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to oracle.sql.CLOB
```

The CLOB field in my report:

```
<field name="clob_data" class="oracle.sql.CLOB"/>
```

And this is how I display my CLOB field:

```
<textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{clob_data}.getSubString( 1l, ( new Long( $F{clob_data}.length() ) ).intValue() )]]></textFieldExpression>

<textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader($F{clob_data}.getAsciiStream())).readLine()]]></textFieldExpression>
```

There is no `textFieldExpression for class="oracle.sql.CLOB"`

Any easy way to handle this?

Update: My problem would be like this guy, still no solution:

http://iswwwup.com/t/1b800f433463/how-jasperreports-display-clob-field-with-html-tags.html

Comment: It seems jasperreports has problems converting _from_ string to CLOB, not vice versa. Maybe you have problems with your query or database setup?

Comment: No. My query was working fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Done. I found some trick to solve this unanswered problem.
As we know **Varchar2** only support 4000 of characters. So i came up with a trick to cut by part of my CLOB data in query like this:

```
select DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(clob_field, 4000, 1) as clob_data_1 
select DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(clob_field, 2000, 4001) as clob_data_2
from table
```

as you can see, i separately put my CLOB data in clob_data_1 and clob_data_2 so it still act as a String. In my case, i just used 6000 of characters. **DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR** is a oracle function to substring data.

In my report, i can simply combine this column just like this:

```
$F{clob_data_1}+$F{clob_data_2}
```

I hope with this solution, it can help some people that have similar problem like me.

Comment: What if you don't know size of your clob? How can we handle it dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

Try to make a String obiect from the CLOB either by appending "" or by calling String.valueOf()

Comment: no luck. `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to oracle.sql.CLOB`